# Which one is a correct senntence?

Tags: grammar

1. I have entered the marks of Maths in the booklet.
2. I have entered the Maths' marks in the booklet.

Comment: Welcome; some context could be added. The British English uses *marks* and the (plural) *Maths* to mean different things from American English so I have to guess here in the comments. Please describe just what you are trying to say with the sentence. I think you mean "I have written down the test scores, or grades, of the students Math tests in the booklet". Thank you.

Comment: There should be no possessive apostrophe. You wouldn't say *the Geography's marks* or *the History's marks*. Instead, it would just be *the Geography marks* and *the History marks*.

Comment: And it would be 'the marks _for_ Maths', not _of_.